# IE6 cannot download javascript files over HTTPS

Tags: https, richfaces, internet-explorer-6

I'm totally stumped here, so any ideas would be appreciated.

I have a RichFaces application, which recently became non-functional when used from IE6. The problem began when I included the following line in my main template:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>
```

This results in the following generated HTML:

```
<script src="/AgriShare/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finaljquery.js.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By "non-functional" I mean that pages no longer load, b/c the first page appears to hang the browser for a long time, and then all references to jQuery say that the object was not defined. Eventually this appears to put IE6 in a state where further clicks do nothing.

After a lot of trial and error I have established the following:

- The app still works in Chrome, Firefox and IE8
- The app still works in IE6, if I switch to HTTP. So, the problem appears to be related to HTTPS, which I can't dispose of.
- I further narrowed down the problem by trying to manually request `3_3_3.Finaljquery.js.jsf` in IE6 address bar. It asks me if I want to save the file (so it can see it is there), but when I say 'Save', it hangs for about 5 seconds and then says:

> Internet Explorer cannot download 3_3_3.Finaljquery.js.jsf from [host_name].
>
> The connection with the server was reset.

- Doing the same download over HTTP succeeds.
- Gradually reducing the size of the file, I noticed that the download eventually succeeds over HTTPS, if I get the files size below ~ 110KB. There is no specific size it works at though. I tried the same trick with `prototype.js` and it worked at a different size value.

I can't trace the SSL session, b/c I cannot get access to the certificate's private key, so now I have absolutely no clue what to try next.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your server, by chance, using Server Name Indication (SNI)? IE6 and other old browsers doesn't support this.

Comment: Do you have to support IE6? It's use is noticeably declining around the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for debugging.  It can handle SSL.

You might also want to consider hosting the server yourself and taking a look at the server log.

Comment: Wow, that's a great piece of software. An out of the box "man-in-the-middle attack" is pretty cool :). When I run my requests through Fiddler, IE6 is working over HTTPS! Does that mean that the HTTPS server I'm using is misconfigured?

Comment: Fiddler inserts itself in between the browser and my server. The fact that everything works correctly with Fiddler means that Fiddler is not making the same mistake IE6 is making while communication with my server. Also, it means that Fiddler is not making the same mistake as my server, while communicating with IE6. So, this confirms what I already suspected (i.e. problem is with IE6 <=> Server communication over HTTPS), but does not get me any closer to figuring out what to do about it... :(

Comment: @jdigital: yes, I might. I'll have to ask the operations team to provide them for me tomorrow. Considering that this is a government server, I suspect I'll have the logs in a week :). But that sounds like a good place to look though. Thanks!

Comment: @ValBlant: As I suggested earlier, you might consider hosting the app yourself to see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ValBlant: Also, if you do a little searching, you may come up with hints, for example [this discussion](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic5807.html)

Comment: It looks like the problem appeared when the server was upgraded from Oracle Web Cache 10g to 11g. Rolling back to 10g makes the problem go away, so this is a confirmed server config issue. I'll post the actual solution once the Operations guys figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by turning off compression of javascript files in Web Cache.

Sounds like the problem might be related to this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;327286